# Bootstrap columns inside panel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create 3 columns inside a panel but for some reason the xs viewport does not look right. The last column moves below the row. You can see it on [this jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/k8pd1epw/1/)

Any clues what I might be doing wrong?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="panel panel-default content-parent">
        <div class="panel-header content-header">
          <div class="row content-header-assets">
            <div class="col-xs-1">
              <i class="fa fa-angle-left content-header-actions"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-10">
              <h1 class="content-header-title text-center">Some long text</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">
              <i class="fa fa-angle-right content-header-actions"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="content-body col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-9 col-lg-7 block-center">

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer content-footer text-center">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.col-*-1` is 8.33333333% of the space provided, so your content (the `.fa .fa-angle-right/left`) doesn't fit since it's larger than 8.333%. This is not the best solution for this type of layout, but you can try `.col-xs-2` on the left and right and `.col-xs-8` on the middle.

Comment: Yea thats kind of what I did after that.. col-xs-2 and col-sm-1.. Thanks anyway